# Meteor File upload to S3

Tags: meteor

I followed steps from https://github.com/Lepozepo/S3 to setup S3 upload with Meteor. I have created s3.js within server folder and placed

S3.config = {
key: 'accesskey',
secret: 'secretkey ',
bucket: 'my-bucket-name'
};

When i try to upload file to S3, i did not see any error. The callback function returns

Object { percent_uploaded: 100, uploading: false, url: "http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/gfcNkm53mm2NNxGwY.jpg", secure_url: "https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/gfcNkm53mm2NNxGwY.jpg", relative_url: "gfcNkm53mm2NNxGwY.jpg" }

on console.

But there is no file in my bucket on S3.

Also i added,

BrowserPolicy.content.allowOriginForAll('https://s3.amazonaws.com')

My CORS

AllowedOrigin - *, AllowedMethod - GET,PUT, POST, AllowedHeader - *

Bucket policy:

Also i added bucket policy.

I created bucket before 4 hour. May i know what is the issue?

Is it CORS issue?

Comment: I would recommend using cfs:filesystem and cfs:s3, and I think there might be something wrong with ur url syntax, mine is like: https://my-region.amazonaws.com/bucket/collection_name/id+name.jpg

Comment: BrowserPolicy.content.allowOriginForAll('s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com') i wrongly added my region on BrowserPolicy. Now its working using lepozepo s3.